# Official Definition of sscanf() Format String?

Tags: c++, c, standards, scanf

I'm implementing my own version of `sscanf()` in a different language (not C or C++).

I'm mostly finished. I'm just trying to wrap up some of the finer details of the meaning of the format string. However, searching the web, I'm finding that not all documentation for `sscanf()` is the same.

For example, some say `%i` handle octal and hexadecimal while others don't even include this format type. And some discuss `%[` while others do not. In addition, some details just seem to be omitted.

What is the most authoritative documentation of exactly how the format string should be interpreted?

I'm not fanatical about complying with the standard. But I would like to be as compatible with any existing format strings as I can.

**EDIT**

If anyone is interested, I've published my [C# implementation of sscanf()](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net) code online.

Comment: C has a standard. Multiple ones, actually, although this particular piece propably didn't change that often.

Comment: @delnan: My question pretty much assumes there is a standard, although I realize there may not be a single standard. I just want to be as compatible as is reasonable to "the standard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See ISO/IEC 9899:1999 7.19.6.2 (fscanf) - this is the last C standard

Comment: Thanks. I Googled that, but didn't get anything useful (or in English).

Comment: @Jonathan Wood - Can send you the standard via email

Comment: That would be cool. I've added my email address to the end of my original question. I'll remove it shortly.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of the standard (or most of the point anyway) is to provide answers for questions like this, so (at least to  me) it seems like a copy of the standard would be the obvious reference. To save some money compared to the real standard, you can pretty easily go from a [draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1539.pdf) of the standard instead.

Comment: Huh? Are you saying there *is* a standard, but that it is not available on the web without paying?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: yes, that's correct. You can get the real standard from http://webstore.ansi.org (among other places) but it costs at least a little money (it looks like it's $30 at the moment). In fairness, as technical books go it's fairly inexpensive, but for most people's use, the free draft works just as well.

Comment: Wow, you learn something new every day. I don't have a problem with companies making money, but charging for a computer-related standards definition in this age of open information on the web really surprises me.

Comment: @Jonathon Wood: The ISO (and ANSI, IEC, etc.) sell standards largely because they have almost no other source of income. Some others (e.g., ECMA) can afford to give standards away, largely because they're more or less "sponsored". The basic question is whether you're willing to pay extra for a standard in the hope of the sponsor having less influence over the result (though in cases like ISO 29500, that's open to question as well).

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to decide what you are implementing. You can follow one of C or C++ standards or some platform specific extension (POSIX, GNU, MSVC).

If you decide to follow one of the standards, just look into it and follow the specifications. For platform specific stuff, you will need to follow the documentation of the specific platform.

Comment: I'm just trying to make a reasonable effort to be as compatible as I can with the largest number of `sscanf()` format strings already out there.

Comment: @Jonathan :) Well, it's still your decision. If you simply specify in the documentation that you are following the C or C++ standard, it should be perfectly clear to everyone what features you support.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing your point. I agree with your comment above but the main person who isn't perfectly clear what features I would be supporting is me.

Comment: @Jonathan Well, you need to choose. Standard mandates the basic set of formatting flags = easier implementation, but fever features. If you choose one of the extensions, you will provide more features, but it will be harder to implement. Just make sure you choose one of them and follow it precisely to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

While you have to purchase the ISO standards, the late draft ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 (ISO C99) which is almost identical is freely available. Here for example: [www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf). The sscanf function is defined in section 7.19.6.7.  However all the format specifier detail is given in the description of fscanf in 7.19.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the C stanard, there's also a POSIX standard which defines sscanf. That one is free, at http://www.unix.org/version3/. As usual with POSIX, it's upwards compatible.